# CCSprite not drawing to Parent

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have one CCSprite class named Fruit and two CCNode classes named FruitManager and GameScene. FruitManager is a child of GameScene, and all of the Fruit class instances are being initialized in an NSMutableArray in FruitManager. I have tried many different ways of getting the instances of the Fruit class to draw to the GameScene class, but none of them have worked. NSMutableArray is being initialized as:

`NSMutableArray *fruitArray;
fruitArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Below that I am adding objects of type Fruit to it. Those Fruit objects are also being added as children to the FruitManager class. I know for a fact that the array is initializing and retaining the objects properly, but I just don't know why they aren't drawing to GameScene.

Comment: If the parent-child relationships are as you say, they should draw. It could be that they were drawing off screen (by any chance ?) ... check positions, transparency, and the .visible property of the sprites.

Comment: I know for sure they aren't drawing off screen. I will check transparency and visible properties though.

Comment: What version of cocos2d ? in v3+ , if the position type is Normalized, and your position is (160,240) ... they are wayyy off screen. check these properties too (as appropriate to your version of cocos)

Comment: Ok so I tried checking the position type and the visible and transparency properties and none of that worked. I did notice however that my animationManager that I have linked to my fruit class is retaining nil in the array so I'm assuming that's the problem.

Comment: I got it finally! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation manager in my Fruit class was being set to nil. I was not initializing my Fruit correctly in the init method. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but have you added fruit objects in your array to the GameScene

Something like

```
for (int i=0; i < [fruitArray count]; i++) {
            [self addChild:[fruitArray objectAtIndex:i] z:2];//self or GameScene z optional
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. The problem is I have Fruit objects randomly generating into the fruitArray throughout the game. I'm thinking that the only way that code would work is if I were to integrate all the code from the FruitManager into the GameScene.

Comment: i try to understand : the moment you create the fruit object, you add it to the array, so at that moment you add it to the scene

you dont have to iterate all the array for this

if you re in FruitManager that is a child of GameScene, you can use [self.parent addchild your object]